# Why is my page reloading after onChange trigger update?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have added different forms in different methods but when I type anything in input fields, the page reloads keeping the states and again I have to click on the field and type and same cycle happens. It is working fine if I add everything in return. Can somebody tell explain why is this happening and how to stop it?
I am also sharing a piece of code.

```
function MyForm() {
    const [commentForm, setCommentForm] = useState({
        Comment: "",
    });

    const onCommentChange = (obj) => {
        setCommentForm((prevState) => {
            return {
                ...prevState,
                ...obj,
            };
        });
    };

    const IForm = () => (

        <Table>
            <CardBody>
                <Row>
                    <Col className="col-2">
                        <Label>Comment: </Label>
                    </Col>
                    <Col className="col-1">
                        <Input type="text"
                            value={commentForm.Comment}
                            onChange={(e) =>
                                onCommentChange({ Comment: e.target.value })} />
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </CardBody>
        </Table>
    );
    return (
        <div>
            <IForm />
        </div>
    )
}
export default MyForm
```

Comment: `e.target.value` is a string, not an object; it makes no sense to spread it with `...`. What your `setCommentForm()` should return is `...prevState, Comment: obj` (I am assuming you have your reasons to set and handle the state as you did, although your code example suggests you could do it in a much more simple way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because you define `IForm` as A component inside the current component which is not correct. so you have two solutions.

**1** - move `IFORM Component` outside the current react.

```
function MyForm() {
  const [commentForm, setCommentForm] = React.useState({
    Comment: ""
  });

  const onCommentChange = (obj) => {
    setCommentForm((prevState) => {
      return {
        ...prevState,
        ...obj
      };
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <IForm commentForm={commentForm} onCommentChange={onCommentChange} />
    </div>
  );
}
export default MyForm;

const IForm = ({ commentForm, onCommentChange }) => (
  <Table>
        <CardBody>
            <Row>
                <Col className="col-2">
                    <Label>Comment: </Label>
                </Col>
                <Col className="col-1">
                    <Input type="text"
                        value={commentForm.Comment}
                        onChange={(e) =>
                        onCommentChange({ Comment: e.target.value })} />
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </CardBody>
  </Table>
);
```

**2** - declare the IForm as a normal function inside the current component.

```
function MyForm() {
  const [commentForm, setCommentForm] = React.useState({
    Comment: ""
  });

  const onCommentChange = (obj) => {
    setCommentForm((prevState) => {
      return {
        ...prevState,
        ...obj
      };
    });
  };

  const form = () => (
    <Table>
        <CardBody>
            <Row>
                <Col className="col-2">
                    <Label>Comment: </Label>
                </Col>
                <Col className="col-1">
                    <Input type="text"
                        value={commentForm.Comment}
                        onChange={(e) =>
                            onCommentChange({ Comment: e.target.value })} />
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </CardBody>
    </Table>
  );

  return <div> {form()} </div>;
}
export default MyForm;
```

Comment: Is there any other way? Because there is 1000s of lines of code and it would take a lot of time in changing.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the IForm component is declared inside the MyForm Component. Which means that whenever the state of MyForm Component changes it will refresh its dom tree. And when the dom will rerender the functional component IForm will be executed again that's why you'll always lose the focus of the input but you never lose the state of the MyForm component.

To stop it from being happening either declare the IForm Component outside of the MyForm component or move the jsx of the IForm inside the Return of MyFOrm component.

Answer (score 0):

You should just `setCommentForm` the value. I don't think you need to spread the prevState.

What you want to achieve is to set the state value to the new one.

Also, you don't have any `useEffect` right?

Comment: What is the need of useEffect in this?

Comment: None, that's why I was asking if you had use it anywhere. Did you solve it? (:

Comment: I did got my answer. Thanks for helping anyways. :)